# Android Management api - Is it possible to get device id/name in android app? ( Device specific QR is not possible, Generating Policy specific

Tags: android, android-management-api

I am using android management api and Want to fetch device id from Android Management api. So send data to Custom server (Own backend).

https://developer.android.com/work/managed-configurations

This is already used for fetching policy name and other details. It's not useful for above requirement

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Method: enterprises.devices.list](https://developers.google.com/android/management/reference/rest/v1/enterprises.devices/list?hl=en) to list all the devices under the enterprise. In the JSON response, you can get the device’s name from the [Device resource](https://developers.google.com/android/management/reference/rest/v1/enterprises.devices#Device) in the form `enterprises/{enterpriseId}/devices/{deviceId}`.